# Is there any tool to detect lines of html/css code that are actually not being used anymore?

Tags: css, html

I recently redesigned my website and now I have many lines of code that are not being used anymore when the website loads. Its really tedious to go through all the lines manually, is there any tool for this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give examples of HTML code that isn't being used?  I can see how you could have a great deal of unused CSS but not HTML.

Comment: How do you define "not being used"?

Comment: What not used anymore means in this context? If they are commented out  like this <!-- --> it's easy. Please elaborate a little.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert Yes, i meant css in large, not html. AndrewMarshall how to know whether the js include files like "<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/scripts/jquery.1.4.2.js"></script>" are being used or not in my redesigned html?

Comment: You should know that yourself.

Comment: It's of no use to you now, but for future reference, I'd strongly suggest scrapping CSS when you redesign. Having to maintain CSS through multiple site redesign is, as you've found, a huge messy undertaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like http://unused-css.com/ will check for unused CSS on your site.

Unused JS will be much tougher.

Comment: I should point out that I found that in about two seconds Googling for "Unused CSS".

Comment: The problem is that this service only offers help for sites that are more static in nature. Sites and especially web applications are trending more toward single-page JavaScript applications and setups where views and page elements are generated, modified and removed on the fly. So the views are always changing and thus a lot of CSS that is actually used will show up as unused. So do be mindful of this before consulting it and removing any of your CSS.

Comment: @AndyLester I have no idea why I din't just google it! Well, I gained about 22 reputation pts & a bronze over this! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Found these for fixing html,

- http://fixmyhtml.com/
- http://unfuckmyhtml.com/

and these for fixing css

- http://unused-css.com/
- https://github.com/giakki/uncss (I personally recommend this. Great tool!)